# How to shrink /sys/fs/cgroup memory

Tags: partitioning, ram

I am facing issue while resizing the memory in my Ubuntu

I am having total of 40GB memory out of which 16GB is utilized by `udev` and 15GB is allocated to `/dev/xdva1` and 16GB to `/sys/fs/cgroup`. But `/sys/fs/cgroup` is using 0% memory, so I want to reduce its size to less than 10GB and allocate the remaining to `/dev/xdva1`.

I tried `fdisk` and other commands but thing work out. I tried changing `/etc/fstab` but am facing "unable to swap" or "recovery impossible" messages.

Can someone help me to shrink the memory and assign it to the required mount point?

here is my output bytes

hi this is my output from aws ubuntu instance
[df -h output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfWTU.png)

Comment: You're confusing some things here. Could you please add the output of `df -h` to your question? That would help me to explain things with the exact names and numbers as they are on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up virtual and real file systems here.

`udev` is a virtual file system type which is not backed by any disk storage but exists purely in memory, just like e.g. `tmpfs`, `cgmfs` or `none`.

The only real file systems stored on your hard disks or removable storage are those listed as `/dev/sd??`, `/dev/hd??`, `/dev/mmcblk??`, `/dev/xdv??` or anything similar.

The size reported by `df` for real file systems equals the real size of their containing partitions on the disk, with used/available space being what you expect.

For virtual file systems, the reported size is how big they may grow at most in memory. In case of e.g. a `tmpfs`, this defaults to half of your available RAM unless specified otherwise when mounted. This does not mean that this amount of RAM is reserved and unavailable for the rest of the system though. They only always take as much RAM as they need, which is shown as used space, not more. The available space is just how much it would be allowed to grow, but normally all those virtual file systems used by the systems never grow large.

That said, I hope you understand why you can not allocate any of the space theoretically available to some of Ubuntu's virtual file systems to your real physical partitions on your hard disks.